# SQL NOT operator not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query which does something like this:

```
SELECT
    IIF (
        col1 = 'A' OR
        col2 = 'B' OR
        col3 = 'C'
    , 'true', 'false') TEST1,  -- test some conditions
    IIF (
        NOT (
            col1 = 'A' OR
            col2 = 'B' OR
            col3 = 'C'
        )
    , 'true', 'false') TEST2  -- same as TEST1, but wrap NOT operator around it
FROM
    -- some tables and conditions
```

The two columns TEST1 and TEST2 should be opposites, but TEST2 is always false. Any idea why?

Comment: Your second will only spit out `TRUE` when `col1` is not equal to `A` AND `col2` is not equal to `B` AND `col3` is not equal to `C`. Try setting their values all to `D` and run this. Essentially if ANY one of those tests inside your `NOT()` returns `TRUE` then the `NOT()` will change the `TRUE` to a `FALSE`. So they must all be `FALSE` to return a `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is this:

```
col1   col2   col3
'D'    'E'
```

Here `col1 = 'A' OR col2 = 'B' OR col3 = 'C'` results in `unknown`, because `NULL = 'C'` does neither evaluate to true nor to false. The expression is not true, so the first `IIF` results in `'false'`.

`NOT (col1 = 'A' OR col2 = 'B' OR col3 = 'C')` is also `unknown`, as the reverse of `unknown` is neither true nor false. The expression is not true, so the second `IIF` results in `'false'`, too.

Can this be the cause for the results you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff pointed out that your code will not work as intended if some values are `null`, other than that you should be seeing outcome you are expecting.

Remember that `null = 'A'` is `null`, not `false`. ergo `not(null = 'A')` is also `null`.

```
create table t (col1 char(1), col2 char(1), col3 char(1));
insert into t values
 ('A','A','A')
,('A','B','C')
,('A','B',null)
,(null,null,null)
,('Z','Z',null)
,('Z','Z','Z');

select *,
    iif (   (col1 = 'A' or col2 = 'B' or col3 = 'C'), 'true', 'false') as test1,
    iif (not(col1 = 'A' or col2 = 'B' or col3 = 'C'), 'true', 'false') as test2
from t;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/CRYH34782

returns:

```
+------+------+------+-------+-------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | test1 | test2 |
+------+------+------+-------+-------+
| A    | A    | A    | true  | false |
| A    | B    | C    | true  | false |
| A    | B    | NULL | true  | false |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | false | false |
| Z    | Z    | NULL | false | false |
| Z    | Z    | Z    | false | true  |
+------+------+------+-------+-------+
```

---

You could wrap your columns in `isnull()` or `coalesces()` to supply replacement values for `null`.

- [`isnull()` - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)
- [`coalesce()` - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)